# Codificação utf-8 em ficheiro XML para gerar RSS

Tags: php, xml, rss

Num site de notícias quero gerar uma página de RSS com as notícias do dia. A página é bem gerada, mas se ao gerar houver uma notícia com acentos ou caracteres especiais a geração falha. No meu código tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

    $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
    $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>RSS feed</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>RSS feed</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
    $rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2014 xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</copyright>';

    $data = date("Y-m-d");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias WHERE data = '$data' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $title = $row['titulo'];
        $title = $title;
        $description = $row['intro'];
        $date = $row['data']." - ".$row['hora'];
        $link = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/detalhe.php?id=".$row['id'];
        $image = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/images/resize_listagem/".$row['foto'];

        $rssfeed .= '<item>';
        $rssfeed .= '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
        $rssfeed .= '<description>' . $description . '<![CDATA[<br><img src="' . $image . '" />]]></description>';
        $rssfeed .= '<link>' . $link . '</link>';
        $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' .$date. '</pubDate>';
        $rssfeed .= '</item>';
    }

    $rssfeed .= '</channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '</rss>';

    echo $rssfeed;
?>
```

Já experimentei mudar o cabeçalho para UTF-8 mas sem sucesso. Também já experimentei o utf8_encode e tambem não deu. A tag  é o que faz gerar o erro. Porque a tag  com caracteres especiais não dá erro. Os campos na BD estão guardados como utf8_general_ci

Comment: Já tentaste usar o [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php) do PHP para gerar o XML? É o que uso e não tem qualquer problema, já te trata desses problemas de encoding. Tu ai terias de tratar disso a mão, uma vez que estas a escrever tu.

Comment: @JorgeB. ainda não experimentei. Se não conseguir resolver deste modo opto pela sua sugestão. obrigado

Comment: A influência nisso está ligado como os dados estão gravados na sua tabela, ou seja, qual codificação você ta usando é o latin? Se for pode usar um utf8_encode

Comment: @HarryPotter, os campos na BD estão guardados como utf8_general_ci

Comment: @pc_oc eu edite a resposta para outra! tente por favor

Comment: Apesar de a DOM cobrir bem mais terreno acho que gerar um XML simples com ela seria matar formiga com bala de canhão. Nesses casos, a XmlWriter, também nativa, pode ser uma boa pedida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione essa linha antes da `$query`, `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");

$rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$rssfeed .= '<channel>';
$rssfeed .= '<title>RSS feed</title>';
$rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</link>';
$rssfeed .= '<description>RSS feed</description>';
$rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
$rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2014 xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</copyright>';

$data = date("Y-m-d");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias WHERE data = '$data' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title =  $row['titulo'];
    $title = $title;
    $description = $row['intro'];
    $date = $row['data']." - ".$row['hora'];
    $link = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/detalhe.php?id=".$row['id'];
    $image = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/images/resize_listagem/".$row['foto'];

    $rssfeed .= '<item>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>' . $description . '<![CDATA[<br><img src="' . $image . '" />]]></description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>' . $link . '</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' .$date. '</pubDate>';
    $rssfeed .= '</item>';
}
```

*Referência:*

- [mysql_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

Comment: Não, a minha tabela está guardar a utf8_general_ci em todos os campos. O que é estranho é apenas no campo title dar ester erro. obrigado

Comment: Adicione antes daquela query um comando assim: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: Talvez seja cache dá uma olhadinha nisso! porque é padrão !!!

Comment: a partir do momento que mudo o hearder para utf-8, deixa de aparecer.. Apenas no safari fica bem

Comment: @pc_oc ainda não deu certo? desculpas eu não entendi ?

Comment: sim já consegui! obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Uma idéia inicial seria usar `htmlentities` para não ter problemas com encoding:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = htmlentities( $row['titulo'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8' );
```

Caso não seja suficiente, pode forçar a saída em `UTF-8`:

```
    $title = utf8_encode( htmlentities( $row['titulo'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8' ) );
```

Mas neste caso, precisa atualizar estas duas linhas para `utf-8` também:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
$rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
```

Se ainda tiver problemas, pode usar um `CDATA` no title:

```
    $title = '<![CDATA['.utf8_encode( htmlentities( $row['titulo'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8' ) ).']]>';;
```

Esta solução pode ser estendida a outros campos, conforme a necessidade.